# How to solve the "unresolved external symbol" link error in visual c++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, visual-c++, visual-studio-express

I Have the Visual Studio C++ 2008 Express Edition.

I am trying to compile a program but I am getting the following Link Error:

```
1>MSVCRT.lib(wcrtexew.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _wWinMain@16
```

What I tried to do:

I found this on google:

```
For Visual C++ .NET: In the Advanced category of the Linker folder in the Project Properties dialog box, set the Entry Point to wWinMainCRTStartup.
```

It was intended to work but didn't. How do I compile this app?

The code is stupidly simple:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
int main( int argc, char ** argv )
{
}
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are multiple ways to solve this:

1. Create a console application
2. Change the Subsystem console now in the linker settings ( Project Settings -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem (select Console))
3. Change the entry point in the linker settings to mainCRTStartup (Project Settings -> Linker -> Advanced -> Entry Point)
4. Define `int CALLBACK WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance,HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,LPSTR lpCmdLine,int nCmdShow );` instead of `int main(int argc, char const ** argv)`
5. Change the Character Set to Use Unicode Character Set (Project Settings -> General->Character Set )

Comment: Thanks. I tried the your 3rd option and It worked. About the number two, I didn't found the "Subsystem" option in Linker, advanced options, where is that?

Comment: Sorry my bad it is in Project Settings -> Linker -> System not in Project Settings -> Linker -> Advanced. I have corrected it in the post :)

Comment: this is a nightmare

Answer (score 3):

It looks like when you created your project you selected a GUI (Win32, MFC, etc) program.
Those programs have a WinMain() instead of a main().

What you want is a Console project.

Answer (score 1):

According to [similar questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4845410/error-lnk2019-unresolved-external-symbol-main-referenced-in-function-tmaincr), that error happens when `main` isn't defined.

Maybe for some reason it's compiling a different file?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5836644/error-when-statically-building-a-windows-application#answer-5837391) suggests that maybe your flags are inconsistent.